# Connecting mysql Database to Local WildFly Server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar, wildfly

I'm running a local wildfly server

and i run mysql script in MySQL workbench, the name of database schema is testapp

I created folder in D:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\com\mysql\main

I've got here mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin jar file and module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

then i added dataresource code into standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/testappDS" pool-name="testappDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testapp</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>test</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

But when i make a request from Postman

xxx.xx.x.xxx:8080/restful/test/hospitals/location?lat=24.000000000&lng=46.000000000

it gives me ERROR Internal Server Error (500)

in Command Prompt it shows this error

> 11:41:44,739 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ur
>   i.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   11:41:44,740 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ur
>   i.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>   11:41:44,741 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ur
>   i.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   11:41:44,742 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ur
>   i.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>   11:41:44,743 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ap
>   plication.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>   11:41:44,743 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ap
>   plication.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>   11:41:44,745 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ap
>   plication.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>   11:41:44,746 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ap
>   plication.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>   11:41:44,747 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.
>   servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) 11:41:44,748 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.
>   servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>   11:41:44,749 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.
>   servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>   11:41:44,750 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServle t.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>   11:41:44,751 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) 11:41:44,752
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.jav
>   a:61) 11:41:44,753 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   11:41:44,754 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   org.wildfly.extension.underto
>   w.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssoci
>   ationHandler.java:78) 11:41:44,755 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)
>   at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
>   redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) 11:41:44,756
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociatio
>   nHandler.java:113) 11:41:44,757 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCal
>   lHandler.java:56) 11:41:44,758 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.P
>   redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) 11:41:44,759
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers
>   .AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.jav
>   a:45) 11:41:44,760 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidenti
>   alityConstraintHandler.java:61) 11:41:44,761 ERROR [stderr] (default
>   task-1)    at io.undertow.security.handlers
>   .AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.j
>   ava:58) 11:41:44,762 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSess
>   ionHandler.java:70) 11:41:44,763 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers
>   .SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   11:41:44,764 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.P
>   redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) 11:41:44,765
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at org.wildfly.extension.underto
>   w.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>
> 11:41:44,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.P
>   redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) 11:41:44,767
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.server.handlers.P
>   redicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) 11:41:44,768
>   ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>   11:41:44,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
>   11:41:44,770 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
>   11:41:44,771 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.
>   ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
>   11:41:44,772 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors .executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
>   11:41:44,773 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServer
>   Exchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) 11:41:44,774 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPo
>   olExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 11:41:44,775 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPo
>   olExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 11:41:44,776 ERROR
>   [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.j ava:745)
>   11:41:44,788 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse]
>   (default ta sk-1) The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a
>   response, re-throwing to the  HTTP container:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.mycompany.jeresyrest.Hospitals.nearBySearch(Hospitals.java:87) [c
>   lasses:]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1 .8.0_45]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMe
>   thodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMeth
>   odDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchPr
>   ovider.java:205) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDi
>   spatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>   [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:
>   1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethod
>   Rule.java:302) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
>   ndPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(Resourc
>   eClassRule.java:108) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
>   ndPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(R
>   ootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
>   est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
>   est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
>   st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
>   st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponen
>   t.java:409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
>   Container.java:558) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
>   Container.java:733) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-s
>   ervlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHand
>   ler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.hand
>   leRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar :1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(
>   ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Fin al]
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHan
>   dler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandle
>   r.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0 .15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandle
>   r.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.
>   15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRe
>   quest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.
>   0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstrain
>   tHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
>   [underto w-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleR
>   equest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:
>   1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandl
>   er.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.
>   0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(Se
>   curityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.han
>   dleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest
>   (ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final ]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(Se
>   rvletInitialHandler.java:227)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(Servlet
>   InitialHandler.java:73)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(Se
>   rvletInitialHandler.java:146)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) 
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:7
>   27) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>
> 11:41:44,815 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023:
>   Exception ha ndling request to /restful/test/hospitals/location:
>   java.lang.NullPointerExcep tion
>           at com.mycompany.jeresyrest.Hospitals.nearBySearch(Hospitals.java:87) [c
>   lasses:]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1 .8.0_45]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMe
>   thodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMeth
>   odDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchPr
>   ovider.java:205) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDi
>   spatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>   [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:
>   1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethod
>   Rule.java:302) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
>   ndPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(Resourc
>   eClassRule.java:108) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHa
>   ndPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(R
>   ootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
>   est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequ
>   est(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
>   st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleReque
>   st(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponen
>   t.java:409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
>   Container.java:558) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(Servlet
>   Container.java:733) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-s
>   ervlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHand
>   ler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.hand
>   leRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar :1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(
>   ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Fin al]
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHan
>   dler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandle
>   r.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0 .15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandle
>   r.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.
>   15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRe
>   quest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.
>   0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstrain
>   tHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
>   [underto w-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleR
>   equest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:
>   1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandl
>   er.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.
>   0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(Se
>   curityInitialHandler.java:76)
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.han
>   dleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateH
>   andler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest
>   (ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final ]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(Se
>   rvletInitialHandler.java:227)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(Servlet
>   InitialHandler.java:73)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(Se
>   rvletInitialHandler.java:146)
>   [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) 
>   [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:7
>   27) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]

any solutions?

Comment: Please add the error message and stacktrace you're getting (you should find it in the server log).

Comment: @JiriTousek i added the error message

Comment: There's this line in the error log:

`java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mycompany.jeresyrest.Hospitals.nearBySearch(Hospitals.java:87)`.

So have a look at line 87 in Hospitals.java to see if you can spot where a `null` might be dereferenced. If not, please post the Hospitals.nearBySearch() code as well.

Comment: @JiriTousek even when I try this : xxx.xx.x.xxx:8080/restful/test/hospitals/doctor  it gives me not found 404   So i think it can't connect to mysql database and i don't know why?